# Implicit differentiating vxcosx^2

Tags: implicit-differentiation

I have been trying to implicitly differentiate $$y = 2vx\cos (x^2)$$, where y, v and x are variables. All I need to know is how to differentiate$$ 2vx\cos(x^2)$$ implicitly.

What I am thinking if is that, by using product rule I will need to differentiate v once, then$ x$ once and then$\ cos(x^2)$ once. Is this the right approach ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you please write your attempt.

Comment: My attempt goes like this, y'= 2( v'xcosx^2 + v(1)cosx^2 + vx(-2xsinx^2))

Comment: Are you trying to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or a different derivative?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$y = 2vx\cos (x^2)$$ is a product of three function so you have to apply product rule carefully.

Note that if you have $$y=f(x)g(x)h(x)$$ then $$y'= f'(x)g(x)h(x)+
f(x)g'(x)h(x)+f(x)g(x)h'(x)$$

You should be able to take over from here.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it !